# Invoke which system command from R to get location of executable

Tags: r, command-line, system

I am try to get the location of an executable using the command line, but all from R. I want to eventually assign this location to a variable in R.

Using the system() command for example, this works fine:

```
x <- system('ls', intern = TRUE)
```

x is a character vector of length number of files in the home directory.

I want to specifically use the which command to get the location of bq, if I run this from the terminal I get:

[image: Works fine in terminal]
From R, I expected this to work

```
x <- system('which bq', intern = TRUE)
```

results in:

[image]

How can I get the location of bq from R?

The solution needs to be dynamic in the sense that it can get the location of bq if it is run on a different machine with differing paths, etc.

Comment: What OS? Status 1 means it's not finding anything, which may be a product of how you're setting your PATH.

Comment: I don't know why `system` is failing, but it's worth noting that the documentation for that function recommends that you use `Sys.which` instead for this specific purpose.

Comment: @alistaire I've made no effort to setting the PATH, forgive my ignorance but how would I do this in this scenario? I'm running macOS Sierra

Comment: @ChrisHaug I'd like to invoke this with system, but even when I do Sys.which(c('bq', 'ftp')) I get a get a "" for bq and "/usr/bin/ftp" for ftp

Comment: Binary files (like R) have to be somewhere on your PATH, which is a string of directories where the system will search for binaries. Even if you're not setting it, one exists. Check it with `echo $PATH` in Terminal and `system('echo $PATH')` within R. The results may well be different, as if you set your PATH via `~/.bash_profile`, it only effects Terminal, not other apps. A universal alternative is `/etc/paths.d/`, or just put all your binaries in `/usr/local/bin/`, or symlink them there. That's what [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) does. If you can use it, do; it will save you these headaches.

Comment: @alistaire Thanks, this was very helpful. The issue is the bq location in downloads is not in the PATH in R. The final step is where do i move the whole folder google-cloud-sdk in 'google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq' from Downloads to in usr/local/bin? (put all binaries in /usr/local/bin/ approach). I tried a few things but cannot get it right. Sorry to expand on the original question so much.

Comment: It would have to be just the binary. If you don't want to do that (not unreasonable sometimes), just [make a symlink](https://gigaom.com/2011/04/27/how-to-create-and-use-symlinks-on-a-mac/).

Comment: I tried that, I moved it such that it was /usr/local/bin/bq (which is what which bq results in (works in R as well through system()). The issue now is the bq command does not work; trouble finding some python files (it works when I move it back to its original location in /Downloads. I assumed it needs the contents of the whole folder. I tried moving the full folder to /usr/local/ but then bq cannot be found this way.